# Trying to install KaTeX as a dependency to Raneto

Tags: node.js, markdown

Using [Raneto](http://raneto.com/), and I have installed katex to the project by running:

```
npm install katex
```

However, when I run Raneto, math blocks don't compile.

I have tried using:

```
var katex = require('katex');
```

in a number of different .js files, but this doesn't seem to have worked. I'm not really familiar with Node.js or Javascript.